# Analytical simulation of a cooling channel in an engine block - temperature evolution in time

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

Not long ago someone (here) asked a question about engine block water cooling, suggesting that the advection equation might be of use for that problem. I understood this not to be the case and promised a different kind of  approach. But I defaulted on that promise when I realised just how complex this problem is.

Ever since I've been trying to develop a very simple model of engine block water cooling, with a view of at least understanding some aspects of it.

---

A cylinder of outer radius $R_{out}$ and length $L$ has a central cooling channel of radius $R_{in}$ with a coolant running through it:

[image: Cooling channel]

Obviously the system is made up of **two coupled subsystems**:

1. The cylinder:

We assume there are significant temperature gradients, so here Fourier's equation applies, for a function $u(r,x,t)$:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{\alpha}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\Big(r\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\Big)+\alpha\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$$
Developed and with PDE shorthand:
$$u_t=\frac{\alpha}{r}u_r+\alpha u_{rr}+\alpha u_{xx}$$
For simplicity's sake we assume the cylinder to be insulated, so with Fourier we get some boundary conditions (BC):

$$u_r(R_{out},x,t)=0\text{ and }u_x(r,0,t)=u_x(r,L,t)=0$$
Let the initial condition be:
$$u(r,x,0)=T_i$$

Finally the most tricky BC, the one on the cooling channel:

$$h[u(R_{in},x,t)-v(x,t)]=-ku_r(R_{in},x,t)$$

2. The cooling channel:

Here we're looking for a function $v(x,t)$. We assume plug flow with no velocity or temperature ($v$) gradients in the $r$-direction.

Heat is transferred to an infinitesimal channel element by means of Newton's law of convection:

$$\text{d}\dot{q}=h\text{d}A[u(R_{in},x,t)-v(x,t)]$$
$$\text{d}m c_p\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}=2\pi h \text{d}x[u(R_{in},x,t)-v(x,t)]$$
$$\dot{m}c_p\partial v=2\pi h [u(R_{in},x,t)-v(x,t)]\text{d}x$$
$$\frac{\dot{m}c_p}{2\pi h}=[u(R_{in},x,t)-v(x,t)]\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}$$
$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=\frac{2\pi h}{\dot{m}c_p}[u(R_{in},x,t)-v(x,t)]$$
Assume also:

$$v(0,t)=T_0$$

Because the cylinder is insulated, this also means that for $u_t=0$ (that is steady-state):

$$u_E(r,x)=T_0$$

**Toward a solution?**

These coupled PDEs aren't the easiest things to tackle, so trying to approximate/simplify might be a first port of call.

For very high mass-throughput of coolant fluid we can expect the coolant fluid's temperature to hardly change, so:

$$\dot{m}\gg 0\Rightarrow \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=\frac{2\pi h}{\dot{m}c_p}[u(R_{in},x,t)-v(x,t)]\approx 0$$
$$v(x,t)=T_0$$
$$u(R_{in},x,t)=T_0$$
This converts for the last BC for the cylinder to:

$$u_r(R_{in},x,t)=0$$
which is another insulation BC. With the other BCs and IC we get the trivial result:

$$u(r,x,t)=T_i$$

---

So I'm not getting anywhere fast with this. If anyone has some ideas/experience on how to tackle it, I'd be all ears...

Comment: simplifications: first, assume steady-state conditions so you don't have to deal with transient behavior. simplify the layout by representing it flattened into planar areas instead of cylindrical shapes. a crude first-order ("best case") estimate can then be had by assuming that all the heat generated in the engine is carried out of it with the coolant stream, and assuming that when the coolant is leaving the engine, it is at the same temperature as the engine block. This gets rid of thermal gradients in the math.

Comment: Okay, I like your thinking. Some Qs: 1. Should the coolant channel be $1D$ only? 2. For engine heat, can I use a source term $q$? 3. What type of BC for the outside of the 'simulated $2D$ engine block'?

Comment: Assume no heat losses from the engine block to environment EXCEPT via coolant, then you don't need to worry about the BC's. this is OK for a first-order estimate. assume coolant channel is a flat plane with a given surface area. and yes, use a simple source term

Comment: You used the symbol k both for the diffusivity of the block and for its thermal conductivity.

Comment: Ooops, I'm always doing that!

Answer (score 1):

I would start out by looking at some simplified limiting cases, just to get some results under my belt.

One case I would look at is the case where the coolant is flowing so fast that its temperature does not have a chance to change during the time it is in the block.  In this case, the temperature that the coolant presents would always be To.  This would represent the fastest that the cooling could take place.  It would also simplify the math by removing the axial dependence, reducing the problem to transient radial conduction.  I'm sure there is an analytic solution to this.

Next, I would look at a case where the coolant in the channel is very well mixed axially.  So it would be like a continuous stirred tank, with coolant entering at $T_0$, and exiting at the well mixed temperature of T(t).  And, here again, the temperature it would present to the block would be T(t), which changes with time, but not axial position.  This problem too would have no axial dependence for the block, and the temperature would vary only with r and t.

There are other simplifying limiting cases I can think of, but I think I'll stop here for now.

Comment: I'll comment tomorrow, +1 so far from me.

Comment: *So it would be like a continuous stirred tank, with coolant entering at T0, and exiting at the well mixed temperature of T(t). And, here again, the temperature it would present to the block would be T(t), which changes with time, but not axial position.* Hmmm... I don't really see how to do that. I can make that temperature independent of $t$ but not of $x$.

Comment: You would write
$$\pi R_{in}^2L\rho C_p\frac{dv}{dt}=\dot{m}C_p(T_0-v)+2\pi R_{in}hL(u(R_{in},t)-v)$$
or, equivalently, 
$$\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{(T_0-v)}{\tau}+\frac{2h} {\rho C_pR_{in}}(u(R_{in},t)-v)$$where $\tau$ is the coolant residence time $\pi R_{in}^2L\rho /\dot{m}$

Comment: Thanks. I think I've come up with something simpler though.

Answer (score 0):

As a simulation I'm using a $2D$ rectangle with a $1D$ cooling channel (of radius $R_{in}$) A uniform, constant heat source $q$ represents engine heat:

[image: 2D engine block]

The principal equation here is:

$$\alpha(u_{xx}+u_{yy})+q=0$$
with boundary conditions (BC):
$$u_x(0,y)=u_x(L,y)=0$$
$$u_y(x,+H/2)=u_y(x,-H/2)=0$$
These BCs represent no heat loss from the surface of the engine block.

We're interested in the steady-state regime and by definition this means the coolant carries of all the engine heat, or:
$$HLq=\dot{m}c_p(T_1-T_0)\Rightarrow T_1=T_0+\frac{HLq}{\dot{m}c_p}$$
For an infinitesimal cooling channel element $\text{d}x$, with Newton's law of cooling:
$$\text{d}\dot{q}=-h\text{d}A[u(x,0)-T(x)]$$
$$\frac{\text{d} T}{\text{d} x}=-\frac{2\pi R_{in} h}{\dot{m}c_p}[u(x,0)-T(x)]$$
Now we make another assumption (that will get rid of the coupling):
$$T(x)\approx T_0+\frac{HLq}{\dot{m}c_p}x$$
$$\frac{\text{d} T}{\text{d} x}=-\frac{2\pi h R_{in}}{\dot{m}c_p}[u(x,0)-T(x)]=-\frac{HLq}{\dot{m}c_p}$$
$$[u(x,0)-T(x)]=-\frac{HLq}{2\pi h R_{in}}$$
$$h[u(x,0)-T(x)]=-ku_y(x,0)$$
$$u_y(x,0)=\frac{HLq}{2\pi hk R_{in}}$$

---

Briefly recapping:
$$u_t=0 \Rightarrow \alpha(u_{xx}+u_{yy})+q=0\tag{1}$$
$$u_x(0,y)=u_x(L,y)=0$$
$$u_y(x,+H/2)=u_y(x,-H/2)=0$$
$$u_y(x,0)=\frac{HWq}{2\pi hkR_{in}}$$

---

$(1)$ is of course non-homogeneous, so separation of variables won't work. But a comrade from math.SE came to the rescue with the following substitution:
$$u(x,y)=w(x,y)-\frac{q}{4\alpha}(x^2+y^2)$$
$$\alpha\Big(w_{xx}-\frac{q}{2\alpha}+w_{yy}-\frac{q}{2\alpha}\Big)+q=0$$
$$\alpha w_{xx}-\frac{q}{2}+\alpha w_{yy}-\frac{q}{2}+q=0$$
$$w_{xx}+w_{yy}=0$$
Neat! Now we transcribe the BCs:
$$u_x(0,y)=w_x(0,y)=0$$
$$u_x(L,y)=w_x(L,y)=0$$
$$u_y(x,-H/2)=w_y(x,-H/2)=0$$
$$u_y(x,+H/2)=w_y(x,+H/2)=0$$
$$u_y(x,0)=w_y(x,0)=\frac{HLq}{2\pi hkR_{in}}$$
Ansatz:
$$w(x,y)=X(x)Y(y)$$
Separation:
$$\frac{X''}{X}+\frac{Y''}{Y}=0\Rightarrow \frac{X''}{X}=-\frac{Y''}{Y}=-m^2$$
The $X$ ODE:
$$X''(x)+m^2 X(x)=0$$
$$X(x)=A\sin mx +B\cos mx$$
$$X'(0)=mA\cos 0-m B\sin 0=0 \Rightarrow A=0$$
$$X(x)=B\cos mx$$
$$X'(L)=-mB\sin mL=0$$
$$mL=n\pi\Rightarrow m=\frac{n\pi}{L}$$
for $n=1,2,3,...$
So:
$$X_n(x)=B_n\cos\Big(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\Big)$$

---

The $Y$ ODE:
$$Y''(y)-m^2 Y(y)=0$$
$$Y(y)=Ce^{-my}+De^{+my}$$
$$Y'(y)=-mCe^{-my}+mDe^{+my}$$
$$Y'(H/2)=-mCe^{-mH/2}+mDe^{+mH/2}=0$$
$$-Ce^{-mH/2}+De^{+mH/2}=0$$
$$Y'(0)=-mCe^{0}+mDe^{0}=\frac{HLq}{2\pi hk R_{in}}$$
$$-mC+mD=\frac{HLq}{2\pi hk R_{in}}$$
This looks messy but develops quite easily to:
$$Y_n(y)=\frac{HLq}{2\pi hk R_{in}m(1-e^{mH})}\Big(e^{m(H-y)}+e^{my}\Big)$$

---

So that:
$$w_n(x,y)=B_n\frac{HLq}{2\pi hk R_{in}m(1-e^{mH})}\Big(e^{m(H-y)}+e^{my}\Big)\cos\Big(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\Big)$$

---

Using the usual Fourier expansion:
$$B_n=\frac{2}{L}\frac{1}{H}\int_0^L \int_0^{H/2}T_i(x)X_n(x)Y_n(y)\text{d}x\text{d}y$$
$$B_n=\frac{2}{L}\frac{1}{H}\frac{HLq}{2\pi hk R_{in}m(1-e^{mH})}\int_0^L \int_0^{H/2}T_1(x)\Big(e^{m(H-y)}+e^{my}\Big)\cos\Big(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\Big)\text{d}x\text{d}y$$
$$\pi hk R_{in}=\mu$$
$$B_n=\frac{q}{\mu m(1-e^{mH})}\int_0^L \int_0^{H/2}T_i(x)\Big(e^{m(H-y)}+e^{my}\Big)\cos\Big(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\Big)\text{d}x\text{d}y$$
Let: $T_i(x)=T_i(1-\frac{1}{2L}x)$
Then:
$$\int_0^{H/2}\Big(e^{m(H-y)}+e^{my}\Big)\text{d}y$$
$$=\frac{e^{mH}-1}{m}=\frac{L(e^{mH}-1)}{n\pi}$$
$$\int_0^L[T_i(1-\frac{1}{2L}x)]\cos\Big(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\Big)\text{d}x$$
$$=\frac{2LT_i}{\pi^2 n^2}(1-(-1)^n)$$
$$B_n=\frac{2qL^2T_i}{\mu n^4 \pi^4}(1-(-1)^n)$$
$$w_n(x,y)=B_n\frac{HL^2q}{2\mu n\pi (1-e^{mH})}\Big(e^{m(H-y)}+e^{my}\Big)\cos\Big(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\Big)$$
$$w_n(x,y)=\frac{q^2HL^5 T_i}{2\mu^2n^5\pi^5(1-e^{mH})}(1-(-1)^n)\Big(e^{m(H-y)}+e^{my}\Big)\cos\Big(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\Big)$$
$$f(n)=\frac{(1-(-1)^n)}{n^5(1-e^{mH})}$$
This function very quickly decays to $\approx 0$, so a 'first term approximation' is in order.
$$u(x,y)=\frac{q^2HL^5T_i}{2\mu^2\pi^5}\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(n)\Big(e^{m(H-y)}+e^{my}\Big)\cos\Big(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\Big)-\frac{q}{4\alpha}(x^2+y^2)$$
$$u(x,y)\approx - 0.903 \frac{q^2HL^5T_i}{2\mu^2\pi^5}\Big(e^{m(H-y)}+e^{my}\Big)\cos\Big(\frac{\pi x}{L}\Big)-\frac{q}{4\alpha}(x^2+y^2)$$
where $m=\frac{\pi}{L}$.
For $L=H=1$ we can write:
$$u(x,y)=\alpha \Big(e^{\pi(1-y)}+e^{\pi y}\Big)\cos(\pi x)+\beta(x^2+y^2)$$
For $\alpha=24.7$ and $\beta=944$, then $u(1,0)=373$ and $u(0,\frac{1}{2})=473$ and we obtain the following plots (Wolfram alpha):

[image: Engine temperature]

[image: Engine temperature 02]

A plot for $y=0$:

[image]

And one for $x=0$:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have another approximation for you.  Suppose that the mass flow rate of coolant is high enough that its temperature does not change much in passing through your model block.  Then we can use the average of To and the exit temperature to calculate the heat flux from the engine block to the coolant.  Since you are neglecting the thermal inertia of the holdup coolant within the duct, we can then write,  $$\dot{m}C_p(v_f -T_0)=2\pi R_{in}h\left(u(R_{in},t)-\frac{(T_0+v_f)}{2}\right)L$$The solution to this equation for $v_f$ is:
$$v_f=\frac{\lambda-1}{\lambda+1}T_0+\frac{2}{\lambda+1}u(R_{in},t)$$where $\lambda=\frac{\dot{M}C_p}{\pi R_{in}hL}$
That gives an average coolant temperature of
$$\frac{(T_0+v_f)}{2}=\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+1}T_0+\frac{1}{\lambda+1}u(R_{in},t)$$and an average temperature driving force of
$$u(R_{in},t)-\frac{(T_0+v_f)}{2}=\frac{(u(R_{in},t)-T_0)}{1+1/\lambda}$$From this, it follows that the boundary condition at $r=R_{in}$ becomes:
$$-ku_r=\frac{h}{1+1/\lambda}(u(R_{in},t)-T_0)$$This effectively eliminates the coolant from further consideration.  And, the solution to all this is a function only of r and t. This is equivalent to a case in which the coolant is at To throughout, and the heat transfer coefficient is lower by a factor of $1+1/\lambda$.  Note that, as the coolant mass flow rate becomes larger, $1/\lambda$ approaches zero and the reduction factor approaches 1.

Comment: Yeah, nice. Remember though it's steady state, so no $t$. I'm having a bit of trouble plotting my solution, so I need to find the problem there before trying what you're suggesting. Ta.

Comment: Steady state suggestion:  Just add a uniform rate of heat generation per unit volume to the block equation.  Then you'll get just u(r).

Comment: I did that already, no? $q$

Comment: I like the approach, which reminds me of tubular heat exchanger design (all those moons ago). But I don't quite see how you can make $x$ disappear, unless you make $L=\infty$?